# Not able to create Authorize.Net customer profiles through its API

Tags: ruby, authorize.net

Using `authorizenet gem 1.8.9`
ruby `1.9.3`

on trying to create a customer profile I am getting this error

```
require 'authorizenet'

transaction = AuthorizeNet::API::Transaction.new(some_id, some_key, :gateway => :sandbox)

request = AuthorizeNet::API::CreateCustomerProfileRequest.new(nil,nil,nil, 'liveMode')

request.profile = AuthorizeNet::API::CustomerProfileType.new("sumeetyesme1870", "sumeet new","sumeet@example.com")
```

actual request

```
 request
=> #<AuthorizeNet::API::CreateCustomerProfileRequest:0x0000000652d4c8
 @merchantAuthentication=nil,
 @profile=
  #<AuthorizeNet::API::CustomerProfileType:0x000000067c6c98
   @description="sumeet new",
   @email="sumeet@masih.com",
   @merchantCustomerId="sumeetMasih1870",
   @paymentProfiles=[],
   @shipToList=[]>,
 @refId=nil,
 @validationMode="liveMode">


response = transaction.create_customer_profile(request)
```

on printing response

```
puts response.messages.messages[0].code
```

I get `E00003`

```
puts response.messages.messages[0].text
```

> The element 'paymentProfiles' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'customerType, billTo, payment, driversLicense, taxId, defaultPaymentProfile' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.

Comment: Is it possible to output what the actually request generated by Ruby looks like?

Comment: @JohnConde updated the question

Comment: It is possible to get the actual XML this produces? I don't know Ruby so I can't see what the issue is without seeing the XML of the request.